# Porting a different variant (STM32F429ZITx) to STM32F429VITx

Tags: stm32

I have an `FreeRTOS` example running on `STM32F429I-DISCOVERY` / `NUCLEO-F429ZI`, which has the  `STM32F429ZITx` MCU inside. But I wish to port this to a new MCU (`STM32F429VITx`). How do I do it?

The main difference between the two MCUs is:

- ZITx version has more IOs (LQFP144). VITx is LQFT100

I understand the HAL libraries will be the same (won't they?). Just the pin configs will change. Am I right?

Comment: Asked [this](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000AIb6dgSQB/porting-a-different-variant-stm32f429zitx-to-stm32f429vitx) question on ST-Community too. I was told since both the MCUs have the same CPU chip, just the pinouts will change.

Comment: Look at memory sizes too, not just program flash but also RAM, particularly make sure your initial stack pointer traditionally at the top of RAM is in a location which actually exists on the target .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference between ZI and VI is only the physical LQFP package size (Z/V), the memory sizes are identical (I/I). The code will be identical and does not care about the physical package.